# Angular material. Проблема с md-menu и md-select

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Когда открываешь меню или выпадающий список, то на странице появляется backdrop, который мешает взаимодействоваться с остальной страницей, пока открыт выпадающий список либо меню.

я спрятал задники:

.md-select-backdrop, 
.md-menu-backdrop {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

.md-scroll-mask {
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
}

а потом тригерю бакдропы если они есть. Так я могу работать с остальным содержимым страницы и закрывать списки и меню.

Но md-menu не хочет ловить клик на них. Видимо там stopPropagation стоит или что-то подобное.

Как решить эту проблему? Или может есть другой подход? Или я вообще что-то упустил?

```
        function triggerBackdrops() {
            var backdropSelect = $('.md-select-backdrop'),
                backdropMenu = $('.md-menu-backdrop');

            if (backdropSelect.length || backdropMenu.length) {
                backdropSelect.trigger('click');
                backdropMenu.trigger('click');
            }

            console.log('click');

            return true;
        }

        $('body').bind('click', function () {
            triggerBackdrops();
        });
```

Comment: Странно, а откуда там *backdrop*? Вроде у https://material.angularjs.org у стандартных элементов *md-menu* *md-select* нету его же?

Comment: Нет, все есть

http://i.prntscr.com/1d0367ba14424d8e82116769c1da1eb0.png